# Netbeans Platform installer target platform

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I've a problem with the application installers generated by *Netbeans*. I have a Netbeans application project with one module. The Java target platform is set to `1.7`. The development system is **Netbeans 8.0.1** on *Mac OS*. I generate the installers with `"Package as" => "Installers"`.

When i try to run the installer on an Ubuntu with JRE 1.7 installed it fails with an `UnsupportetClassVersionError`. When I run the ZIP-packaged application it works fine.

It seems that the class version of the installer is not compatible to *1.7*.
So, my question is: Is there any way to configure the Java version of the installer itself?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run NetBeans using JDK 1.7. See the file NetBeans 8.0.1/etc/netbeans.conf - there is a property netbeans_jdkhome - change it to point to a JDK 1.7 home and restart NetBeans IDE.